# Why can react-test-renderer only findByType functional components in the same file in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, react-test-renderer, react-testing

Here is the functional component `some-table.jsx` I am testing:

```
import React from 'react';

const SomeTable = ({ somethings }) => (
  <>
    {somethings.map(something => {
      return <SomeRow key={something} something={something} />
    })}
  </>
);

export const SomeRow = ({ something }) => {
  return <p>{something}</p>
}

export default SomeTable;
```

Here is my test file:

```
import { create } from "react-test-renderer";
import SomeTable, { SomeRow } from "../common/ui/some-table";

test("check SomeTable has row", () => {
  const renderer = create(<SomeTable somethings={["Hello", "World"]} />);
  const allRows = renderer.root.findAllByType(SomeRow);
  expect(allRows.length).toBe(2);
});
```

This test passes. However if I move `SomeRow` into its own file it then fails:

`some-table.jsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { SomeRow } from './some-row';

const SomeTable = ({ somethings }) => (
  <>
    {somethings.map(something => {
      return <SomeRow key={something} something={something} />
    })}
  </>
);

export default SomeTable;
```

`some-row.jsx`:

```
import React from 'react';

export const SomeRow = ({ something }) => {
  return <p>{something}</p>
}
```

failure:

```
expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

Expected: 2
Received: 0
```

Any ideas why this might be please? Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1):

In the real-world scenario that these `Some`... test files were created to solve, the problem was caused by React's `memo()` function:

```
import React, { memo } from 'react';
...
export default memo(SomeRow);
```

One workaround for which is the following:

```
const allRows = renderer.root.findAllByType(SomeRow.type);
```

Props to [bensampaio](https://github.com/bensampaio) [for that tip](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/17301). You'll find a bunch of other discussion [on that link](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/17301) too that you might find helpful, including:

Pin `react`, `react-dom`, `react-test-renderer` to `16.11.0`, and most importantly add a dependency to `react-is@16.11.0`, or use a predicate like the following:

```
const elementByType = (type) => (element) => (
    element.type === type // Match non-memo'd
    || element.type === type.type // Match memo'd
);
```

It should also be noted that I did something silly too. The imports were wrong. This:

```
import SomeTable, { SomeRow } from "../common/ui/some-table";
```

Should have been this:

```
import SomeTable from "../common/ui/some-table";
import { SomeRow } from "../common/ui/some-row";
```